# How would I go about refactoring multiple click events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, click, refactoring

I am trying to be more concise with my code, and know there has to be a better way to write this snippet. Any thoughts or tips out there for refactoring?

For context, these click events control divs that popup on respective element click, and exit on another button click.

```
  $('.about-link a').on('click', function() {

    $('#pop1').addClass('pop-wrap-show');
    $('.pop-container').addClass(' animated bounceInUp');

  });

  $('.hero-image').on('click', function() {

    $('#pop2').addClass('pop-wrap-show');
    $('.question-form-container').addClass('animated bounceInUp');

  });

  $('.exit-button').on('click', function() {

    $('.pop-wrap').removeClass('pop-wrap-show');

  });
```

Comment: Since all of them do different stuff, I think this is good.

Comment: You could hard code the class strings but really I agree with @Phiter